# How does a quick-release hood pin mechanism work?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, mechanisms

I am trying to understand, in detail, what is going on inside. What components are involved and interacting. A cross-section view would be very useful.
Seems like there are springs and ball bearing involved but I'm not sure.
Relevant video: https://youtu.be/FZuSmCx4tzg?t=46
Relevant product link:  [https://www.amazon.com/Aluminum-Diameter-Release-Button-Bonnet/dp/B08JLR8F5T](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B08JLR8F5T)
[image: Image of various parts]

Comment: probably a similar mechamism to an air hose coupler ... https://duckduckgo.com/?q=airhose+coupler&iax=images&ia=images

Comment: @jsotola or a click to retract / extend pen, Pierce Brosnan used one in Goldeneye.

Answer (score 1):

You're right, the system operates with spring and ball.
And as pointed out this system is easily found searching using terms like "spring ball release mechanism" or derivatives.

Here's one image with a quick search (found on the third result on images from  patent for a similar mechanism)
[image: link: https://patents.google.com/patent/US9431162B2/en]

**Edit:**
Link:
https://patents.google.com/patent/US9431162B2/en

This patent is for a solenoid system (not exactly the same as the button as pointed out).

Comment: All the same, it would be helpful to describe exactly *how* #142 holds the pin in place until exterior forces on #150 exceed some value. This drawing seems to depend on gravity for the latching mech to work.